# Pros and Cons of a `.port` backend v. a `.host` backend in Varnish

Tags: varnish

At work we have a varnish cluster. All the remote backends us the `.host` value (which I assume is required) but all the configs for the local backend, ie the backend running on the server the config/varnishd is on, use the `.path` value. This morning I had an issue with one of the varnish servers, basically the socket referred to by the `.path` did not exist and so it wouldn't start. I tried various ways to bring the socket back up, but after none worked I switched the varnish config to using the `.backend` value instead. I see this is a benefit, as I can now easily maintain a centralized varnish config without having to worry about compiling each config on a per-server basis (ie removing the `.host` line from the backend that corresponds to the specific server).

Are there significant benefits from using a socket to connect to the local varnish cluster (using hitch for SSL termination if that is a factor)? If all things are equal, I see the using `.host` value to be a superior option because it makes pushing config updates much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.path` for Unix Domain Sockets is a lot faster than using `.host` and `.port` for TCP/IP connections.

If throughput is a concern, please use Unix Domain Sockets as you will get a higher throughput (>100 Gbps over TLS).

If massive throughput is not that important, you can use TCP/IP which doesn't require having a UDS.

For UDS permissions matter, so make sure that both Varnish and Hitch have the right permissions to access the socket. Varnish will create the socket and Hitch will use it.